Azure GOVT Start/Stop Solution v2 Subscription 404
I get the following error when in MAG for logic app create for start/stop.  The subscription is valid and has azure resources.  I am running the logic app when logged in as an Owner.  The same setup in Azure commerical works fine for me.
"ExceptionMessage": "The subscription 'f6fd35ed-4605-4b30-b0cf-97f10ee4d110' could not be found.\r\nStatus: 404 (Not Found)\r\nErrorCode: SubscriptionNotFound\r\n\r\nContent:\r\n{"error":{"code":"SubscriptionNotFound","message":"The subscription 'f6fd35ed-4605-4b30-b0cf-97f10ee4d110' could not be found.
Expecting the logic app to start VMs in my subscription.

I have reproduced in my environment and got expected results:

Make sure that you are using same tenant as the Logic app.
The subscription given should be correct.
Logic app needs to be run in Azure Government environment.
ARM endpoint needs to be configured correctly.

Then you can use below design:

Output:


I think what you test is slightly different.  I am following this Azure Doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/start-stop-vms/deploy.  All my resources are in MAG,

Have you checked all your details are given correct as this should work.
